# Rerun a process in Monit if process stops

Tags: unix, monit

I have a script like this this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
file_put_contents('/home/vagrant/sleep.pid', getmypid());
sleep(9);
exit(0);
```

I want to write my Monit config so it makes sure this application is always running. This is my monit config:

```
set daemon 5
check process program with pidfile /home/vagrant/sleep.pid
   start program = "/usr/bin/php /home/vagrant/myphp.php"
```

But after my program exits Monit doesn't try to run it again. It kinda make sense but I was wondering if there is any way to tell Monit to rerun the process.

Answer (score 2):

After playing around more with Monit, I found that I wasn't running Monit properly.

First you need to add the following config to your monit file:

```
set httpd port 2812 and allow monit:monit
set daemon 5
check process program with pidfile /home/vagrant/sleep.pid
    start program = "/usr/bin/php /home/vagrant/myphp.php"
```

Then run the monit with this command:

```
monit -c monit.conf
```

Now Monit runs in the background and rerun the process if it dies, you may restart or start specific program with :

```
monit -c monit.conf start all
```

OR

```
monit -c monit.conf stop my_role
```